# How (Is it worth) to use condition annotations without spring-boot-autoconfigure?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-configuration

Suppose I am developing a java library such that if it is added to spring boot application, it automatically configures application context. Say, it adds some properties or beans.
Thus, I am going to use `META-INF/spring.factories` file with `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration` property to let spring-boot bootstrap my configuration classes.

I also want this library to be flexible, so I am going to use such [annotations](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.7.13/reference/htmlsingle/#features.developing-auto-configuration.condition-annotations) as @ConditionalOnMissingBean or @ConditionalOnClass etc..

I found out that these annotations are coming from `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure` library.

This library contains lots of particular autoconfigurations such as elasticsearch, groovy or solr, which I am absolutely sure will not use in my application.
Even worse, there are autoconfigurations, such as kafka or jdbc, which will definitely mess into my configurations, so I will need to turn them off manually.

My question is the following. Why can `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure` combine such different concepts? On the one hand, it contains reusable annotations, which come handy if you make a starter library. On the other hand, it has partucular autoconfigurations inside which may or may not be needed. I feel I don't understand something here. It seems to me that there can be some kind of violation of [Common Reuse Principle](https://devlead.io/DevTips/CommonReusePrinciple). Is there a way to make a starter library with flexible conditionals but not bloatet with unused autoconfigurations from `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure` library.?

Sorry if my question sounds somewhat vague, but I really feel like there can be a conceptual misunderstanding on my part.

I see the following solutions, neither of which I like.

1. Humbly use annotations from `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure` and hope autoconfigurations never step into my application.
2. Copy annotations to my starter library not to depend on unneeded autoconfiguraions from  `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure`